# object references not set to an instance of the object

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception

Am running asp.net application with c#.Am using gridview to update and delete the columns.deleting is working fine.if am clicking the update button i got

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

My code is;

```
    protected bool IsRowModified(GridViewRow row)
    {
        int currentID;
        string currentName;
        string currentLocation;
      currentID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys
                                [row.RowIndex].Value);

        currentName = ((TextBox)row.FindControl
                                      ("txtName")).Text;
        currentLocation = ((TextBox)row.FindControl
                                  ("txtLocation")).Text;




        **System.Data.DataRow newRow = originalTable.Select
                (String.Format("ID = {0}", currentID))[0];** //got error in this line

        if (!currentName.Equals(newRow["Name"].ToString()))
        { return true; }
        if (!currentLocation.Equals(newRow["Location"].ToString()))
        { return true; }

        return false;

    }
```

Comment: Where is the "originalTable" defined and initialized?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: and anyway Jeni, edit your question showing us the full exception stacktrace

Comment: Either `originalTable` is null or `originalTable.Select` result is null

Answer (score 1):

Either originalTable is null, or originalTable.Select(...) is returning null.

Could it be that you've deleted the underlying data from `originalTable` and not updated the UI?

An alternative method might be to use the [DataItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx) property of the GridViewRow parameter:

```
protected bool IsRowModified(GridViewRow row)     
{                     
    string currentName = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtName")).Text;
    string currentLocation = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtLocation")).Text;                            
    DataRow newRow = (DataRow)row.DataItem;

    if (!string.Equals(currentName, newRow["Name"].ToString()))         
    { 
        return true; 
    }         
    if (!string.Equals(currentLocation, newRow["Location"].ToString()))         
    { 
        return true; 
    }          

    return false;      
}
```

Answer (score -2):

My guess is that your currentID variable is null or empty.  You should check your values for null or empty before you try to use them.

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentID))
{
   // Continue processing
}
```

Comment: I doubt currentID is the culprit. If there's no dot, there's no `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: `currentID` is an integer - it can't be `null`.

Comment: Ah, Mr. Disappointment, you're right....I missed currentID being assigned as an integer.